# Spark CBO not showing rowcount for queries having partition column in query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cost-based-optimizer

I'm working on Spark 2.3.0 using Cost Based Optimizer(CBO) for computing statistics for queries on done on external tables.

I have a created a external table in spark  :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
eventID string,type string,exchange string,eventTimestamp bigint,sequenceNumber bigint
,optionID string,orderID string,side string,routingFirm string,routedOrderID string
,session string,price decimal(18,8),quantity bigint,timeInForce string,handlingInstructions string
,orderAttributes string,isGloballyUnique boolean,originalOrderID string,initiator string,leavesQty bigint
,symbol string,routedOriginalOrderID string,displayQty bigint,orderType string,coverage string
,result string,resultTimestamp bigint,nbbPrice decimal(18,8),nbbQty bigint,nboPrice decimal(18,8)
,nboQty bigint,reporter string,quoteID string,noteType string,definedNoteData string,undefinedNoteData string
,note string,desiredLeavesQty bigint,displayPrice decimal(18,8),workingPrice decimal(18,8),complexOrderID string
,complexOptionID string,cancelQty bigint,cancelReason string,openCloseIndicator string,exchOriginCode string
,executingFirm string,executingBroker string,cmtaFirm string,mktMkrSubAccount string,originalOrderDate string
,tradeID string,saleCondition string,executionCodes string,buyDetails_side string,buyDetails_leavesQty bigint
,buyDetails_openCloseIndicator string,buyDetails_quoteID string,buyDetails_orderID string,buyDetails_executingFirm string,buyDetails_executingBroker string,buyDetails_cmtaFirm string,buyDetails_mktMkrSubAccount string,buyDetails_exchOriginCode string,buyDetails_liquidityCode string,buyDetails_executionCodes string,sellDetails_side string,sellDetails_leavesQty bigint,sellDetails_openCloseIndicator string,sellDetails_quoteID string,sellDetails_orderID string,sellDetails_executingFirm string,sellDetails_executingBroker string,sellDetails_cmtaFirm string,sellDetails_mktMkrSubAccount string,sellDetails_exchOriginCode string,sellDetails_liquidityCode string,sellDetails_executionCodes string,tradeDate int,reason string,executionTimestamp bigint,capacity string,fillID string,clearingNumber string
,contraClearingNumber string,buyDetails_capacity string,buyDetails_clearingNumber string,sellDetails_capacity string
,sellDetails_clearingNumber string,receivingFirm string,marketMaker string,sentTimestamp bigint,onlyOneQuote boolean
,originalQuoteID string,bidPrice decimal(18,8),bidQty bigint,askPrice decimal(18,8),askQty bigint,declaredTimestamp bigint,revokedTimestamp bigint,awayExchange string,comments string,clearingFirm string )
PARTITIONED BY (date integer ,reporteIDs string ,version integer )
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/home/test/'
```

I have computed statistics on the columns using the following command:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/home/test/")
val cols = df.columns.mkString(",")
val analyzeDDL = s"Analyze table events compute statistics for columns $cols"
spark.sql(analyzeDDL)
```

Now when I'm trying to get the statistics for the query :

```
val query = "Select * from test where date > 20180222"
```

Its giving me only size and not the rowCount :

```
scala> val exec = spark.sql(query).queryExecution
exec: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution =
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter ('date > 20180222)
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `test`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
eventID: string, type: string, exchange: string, eventTimestamp: bigint, sequenceNumber: bigint, optionID: string, orderID: string, side: string, routingFirm: string, routedOrderID: string, session: string, price: decimal(18,8), quantity: bigint, timeInForce: string, handlingInstructions: string, orderAttributes: string, isGloballyUnique: boolean, originalOrderID: string, initiator: string, leavesQty: bigint, symbol: string, routedOriginalOrderID: string, displayQty: bigint, orderType: string, ... 82 more fields
Project [eventID#797974, type#797975, exchange#797976, eventTimestamp#797977L, sequenceNumber#...
scala>

scala> val stats = exec.optimizedPlan.stats
stats: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Statistics = Statistics(sizeInBytes=1.0 B, hints=none)
```

Am I missing any steps here? How can I get the rowcount for the query.

Spark-version : 2.3.0
Files in the table are in parquet format.

**Update**
I'm able to get the statistics for a csv file. Not able to get the same for a parquet file.

The difference between the execution plan for parquet and csv is format is that in csv we are getting a `HiveTableRelation` while for parquet its `Relation`.

Any idea why it so?